# Run jar from eclipse vs. browser

Tags: java, browser, jar, applet

Is there any difference between running a project that is packed as a jar file from within eclipse(where it works fine) and running the resulted jar file from within a browser.

The project consists of an applet which is packed into a jar called from an html page.

I should mention that the jar file is signed.

Thanks.

Comment: security is probably tighter in the browser. if you do networking or file access it might be a problem. not sure how good eclipse is at simulating the restricted env of the browser.

Comment: Basically the program sends a file over the internet to a ftp server. So both sending and networking are used.

Comment: Did you self sign the JAR? What make and version of browser are you testing with, and what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

When running a project in eclipse, by default all security privileges are granted. When running an app in a browser there will be security restrictions that will not allow your program to run correctly. Also check your manifest file in the jar and see if it is configured correctly.